# Создание и проверка цифровой подписи

Tags: c++builder, цифровая-подпись, c++

Доброго времени суток. Как сохранить публичный ключ для ЭЦП в файл и соответственно его потом считать?

Answer (score 1):

Работа с файлами производится стандартными ф-циями библиотеки C++. Это ф-ции [`fopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/), [`fclose`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fclose/), [`fread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/), [`fwrite`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/). Если они не нравятся по каким-либо причинам, а больше нравится работа с потоками - можете использовать классы  [`ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/) и [`ofstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/), хотя они в работе посложнее. Ну, и, конечно, можно работать через Win32API. Т.е. это ф-ции [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx), [`WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747.aspx), [`ReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx) и другие.

Также можно использовать класс [`TFileStream`](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/use_tfilestream.html) из библиотеки VCL, поставляемой со средой C++ Builder. Пример использования приведен на Delphi, но не проблема его адаптировать.

Короче, сколько библиотек и интерфейсов - столько и способов работы с файлами. Выбирайте тот, который Вам удобнее и который Вы считаете более правильным.

P.S. никаких отличий при работе с ЭЦП с файлами по сравнению с обычными данными нет. Поэтому и предложено работать через стандартные ф-ции.

Comment: Как работать с файлами я знаю. а вот как организовать запись именно ключа в файл не могу понять.

Comment: Т.е. я генерирую пару ключей для ЭЦП и не могу извлечь открытый ключ, чтобы потом записать его в файл. ну и соответственно чтобы потом проверить подпись мне нужно извлечь открытый ключ из файла. А вот как это программно сделать до меня не доходит

Comment: Как в памяти представляется ваш ключ? Вам достаточно знать начало блока памяти (иметь указатель на него) и знать длину. А потом передать эти значения как аргументы ф-ции fwrite.